# Watch new folders created in a directory outputting the path of new files

Tags: python, windows, directory

The objective is to watch a folder for change. And if there is new subfolder created inside that watch-folder then -  get the new subfolders path and get contents in it.

I have heard about libraries like watchdog and firstnotication. But I am not able to write code in python for Windows Os.
Any Help is appreciated.

Pseudo-code is like this,

```
Watchfolder="C:/watchfolder"
if newFolderCreated inside WatchFolder:
  print snewsubfolder created name #eg:- C:/watchfolder/newfolder
  cd into newsubfolder
  get .mp4 filepath #eg:- C:/watchfolder/newfolder/hello.mp4
```

Comment: Found this article http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/watch_directory_for_changes.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code below is done using win32.file wrapper API using FindFirstChangeNotification API available in windows OS.
All the documentation for the code below can be found at 
http://timgolden.me.uk/pywin32-docs/win32file.html
You can have simpler ways to do it but this is the most efficient one.
All information is available on
http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/watch_directory_for_changes.html

```
import os

import win32file
import win32con

ACTIONS = {
    1: "Created",
    2: "Deleted",
    3: "Updated",
    4: "Renamed from something",
    5: "Renamed to something"
}
FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY = 0x0001

path_to_watch = "C:/yourpath"
hDir = win32file.CreateFile(
    path_to_watch,
    FILE_LIST_DIRECTORY,
    win32con.FILE_SHARE_READ | win32con.FILE_SHARE_WRITE | win32con.FILE_SHARE_DELETE,
    None,
    win32con.OPEN_EXISTING,
    win32con.FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS,
    None
)
while 1:
   #Right now only directory check is being used and everything else like filecheck is commented
    results = win32file.ReadDirectoryChangesW(
        hDir,
        1024,
        True,
        # win32con.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_FILE_NAME |
        win32con.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_DIR_NAME ,
        # win32con.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_ATTRIBUTES |
        # win32con.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_SIZE |
        # win32con.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_WRITE |
        # win32con.FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_SECURITY,
        None,
        None
    )
    for action, file in results:
        full_filename = os.path.join(path_to_watch, file)
        print(full_filename,ACTIONS.get(action, "Unknown"))
```

You get full path in full_filename and action in Actions.get(action, "Unknown"). Right now it is watched for the update, delete, and create. You can sort it out in actions at top of code or bottom using if. 
After which you can get and print the .mp4 path using glob library

```
import glob
print(glob.glob(full_filename,"/*.mp4"))
```

This will return an array of all .mp4 file-paths in the directory